# Adding air condition (con) CONTROLS to a Peugeot 206

Tags: ac, peugeot, retrofit

I emphasise CONTROL because pug has an air con button. I have heard people say it is too expensive/difficult/ just not worth retrofitting air con to a car but I would like to swap the single button one with a digital control. The interface even fits in the same slot but would there be extra parts? I'm guessing some kind of control unit to increase/decrease temperature as it's currently just a button and manual rotate switch.

I would really appreciate any feedback or experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but it needs a lot of work and probably has to be done by a professional.

First, you need to get the automatic panel with the LED screen. Then you need to change lots of wirings and stuff. The most difficult part is changing the air outlets. On the manual models the air outlets (the ones you use to let the air from outside in you car) are opened and closed manually by adjusting a button, but when you are changing your aircon panel to automatic those outlets have to be replaced.

If you are really interested and don't mind going through all these difficult steps, finding the map of the aircon system of 206 is necessary. Good luck!